# How to implement call control system for PRI lines

Tags: c#, .net, telephony, tapi

Today i come up with in situation where i need to implement system where i need to filter out few number when i call them. My requirement is i have Primary Rate Interface (Pri) network connected to 30 land line telephone sets. With my starting research i am able to find few solution's

- Telephony Application Programming Interface (TAPI)
- Microsoft Unified Communications Managed
- Lync 2013
- asterisk

I am able to achieve above motive by refereeing [TAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-Application-development-using-C-NET) for single connection but still not have any idea about implementation on PRI lines. Asterisk is open source but to implement this we need to tools which are not free. As i am new with this, please give me directions to move on with.

Comment: In order to interface with a PRI, I believe you will need special hardware (usually a PCI card built for that type of interface).  Thus, your tools tend to come from manufacturer's of these cards.  Asterisk can certainly do that but you'll probably need to get on board with one of the cards that works with it.  Does this help?  Check this out:  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+PRI

Answer (score 1):

The learning curve in this area can be wicked complicated, if you don't have T1/ISDN background you may be in for a long tough haul if you try to write PRI call control yourself in C#.

You should probably start by refining your requirements statement, keeping it as technology neutral as possible.  You need to be prepared to explain the business problem you are trying to solve clearly.   E.g. if you need PRI, is it for connecting to the telephone sets, to the telephone company, or both.   What actions happen when you "filter out" telephone numbers?  Focus first on a clear statement of what, rather than how.

As to how, there used to be several companies that produced this sort of hardware/software packages, but over the years one of them (Dialogics) seems to have bought out most of the others hardware vendors, so a lot of the software vendors partner with them.  I'd recommend you start at http://www.dialogics.com and look into solutions partners to see if you can find a close match for your requirements.

Good luck!